# Midnight Commander Undelete not working

Tags: mc

How exactly do I use the 'undelete files' option on mc? Couldn't find anything helful or working for me on the internet, so I'm asking here. Let's say I got a loop0 device and write in the box "loop0". Then I get the "cannot chdir to /undel://loop0". Can someone explain to me how this is working?